# A probabilistic proof of van der Waerden theorem

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Is there an elementary proof of  van der Waerden's theorem on arithmetic progressions using probabilistic methods?

Comment: Do ultrafilters count as probabilistic? ;-)

Comment: Which proof of Szemeredi's theorem do you consider probabilistic?

Comment: There are for example probabilistic versions of regularity lemma and so on. See for example [https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5966](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5966)